# R trouble reshaping matrix to 1 column, byrow T or F same result

Tags: r, matrix

```
m <- matrix(1:9,3,3, byrow = TRUE)
m
m2 <- matrix(m, ncol = 1, byrow = TRUE)
m2
m3 <- matrix(m, ncol = 1, byrow = FALSE)
m3
identical(m2,m3)
desiredM <- matrix(t(m), ncol = 1)
desiredM
```

I create a matrix, and want to create a new matrix 1 column wide, with data filled in by going across, then using the next row down, going across, then next row down and across...ect...

I would assume m2 would yield my desired result, but it doesn't.

I am further puzzled as setting `byrow` `TRUE` or `FALSE` doesn't seem to have an effect.

Thank you for taking time to clarifying this behavior, which must be right, once properly understood.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From `?matrix`

> Non-atomic classed R objects are coerced by as.vector and all attributes discarded.

This means that the vector that is being passed to `matrix` is

```
as.vector(m)
[1] 1 4 7 2 5 8 3 6 9
```

The reason `byrow` doesn't have an effect on your output is it determines how the data from the *vector* are read into the new matrix, not how the values from the old matrix are read out.

So, seeing as `as.vector` coerces the matrix by reading down columns before transversing rows, you probably want to do something like:

```
matrix(t(m), ncol= 1)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
matrix(t(m), ncol = 1)

      [,1]
 [1,]    1
 [2,]    2
 [3,]    3
 [4,]    4
 [5,]    5
 [6,]    6
 [7,]    7
 [8,]    8
 [9,]    9
```